# How to get the selected TableView using multiple TableViews

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, tableview

I'm building a timetable with javafx and I'm using 5 TableViews, each of them for one day of the week (Monday - Friday).
I want to delete a item from a TableView with a Button.
It is no problem for me to delete a Item from one specific TableView. But I want the Button to work for all the TableViews.

So my question is: Is there a method to get the selected TableView?
Not just the selected Item from one TableView.

```
@FXML public void fachLoeschen() {
    TableView<Fach> tableview = new TableView<Fach>();
    //tableview = the TableView in which the selected Item is
        
    int selectedIdx = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (selectedIdx==-1)return;
    Fach fach = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    var alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure you want to delete: "+fach.getFach()+ " ?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    if (alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO) == ButtonType.YES) tableview.getItems().remove(selectedIdx);
}
```

this is the code for the Method. The word 'fach' (i'm german) stands for the course that is put in the Timetable.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you need or is what you are looking for, but have you tried to see which one has focus?

Comment: no, there is no general notion of "selected" of a node (_focused_ might be near, but not necessarily). Application code must design/implement it in terms of domain scope - here f.i. current == Monday - and keep it in sync with ui state at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track which table view last had focus:

```
private TableView<Fach> currentFocusedTable ;

// ...
public void initialize() {

    // existing code...

    for (TableView<Fach> table : listOfAllTables) {
        table.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (isNowFocused) {
                currentFocusedTable = table ;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And then:

```
@FXML public void fachLoeschen() {

    if(currentFocusedTable == null) return ;

    int selectedIdx = currentFocusedTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (selectedIdx==-1)return;
    Fach fach = currentFocusedTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    var alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure you want to delete: "+fach.getFach()+ " ?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    if (alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO) == ButtonType.YES) currentFocusedTable.getItems().remove(selectedIdx);
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, hmm .. possible but more like an approach to the _Y_ part of the problem, isn't it ;) The _X_ seems to be the missing notion of "selected" in modeling the OP's context (which can't be provided by the framework, but must be designed/implemented by application code): that can be imagined to be related to "mostRecentlyFocused", but both are not necessarily the same at all times. Just saying .. :)